# How can get image from a path in to UITAbleViewCell?

Tags: cocoa-touch, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

I have the following path in NSString *path1,

```
/Users/srikanth/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/User/Applications/9E6E8B22-C946-4442-9209-75BB0E924434/Documents/snook.jpg
```

How can I show the image snook.jpg.
I need it to show in UITableViewCell for

```
cell.imageView.image
```

if path1 has the path. I used the following to get the last part of the path1 , snook.jpg.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path1];
NSString *imageString = [url path];
```

But, url is showing as nil.
How can I do it ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the path then you can use the "imageWithContentsOfFile:" method of [UIImage](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
cell.imageView.image = img;
```